# How to enlarge the h1.page-header line of bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to extend the line under a the h1.page-header of bootstrap, please?

Here's a [template](http://jsfiddle.net/3azp9/):

```
<h1 class="page-header">ABC</h1>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean enlarge as in make it thicker, because it's already full width.

Add this to the CSS for the simplest solution.

```
h1.page-header {
    border-width: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I was talking about the width of the bodure. I want to boost its width to the left.

Answer (score 1):

An answer to the revised question. The proper solution for this depends on your page layout, the elements surrounding the h1 and their margins and padding etc. I don't know what your layout is but try these:

Either a) Shift the text to the right

```
h1.page-header {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

or b) Shift the whole header to the left and compensate by moving the text the same distance to the right

```
h1.page-header {
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px
}
```